# Use Golang encoding/xml to encode nested struct

Tags: xml, go, struct

Use Golang encoding/xml to encode nested struct.

I'm implementing function Golang encoding/xml to encode nested struct:
Expected:

```
<Request>
    <Types>
        <Type>
            <Type>Type1</Type>
        </Type>
        <Type>
            <Type>Type2</Type>
        </Type>
        ...
    </Types>
</Request>
```

These are the struct i have created:

```
type Request struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Request"`
    TypeNode []TypeNode `xml:"Type"`
}
type TypeNode struct {
    TypeElement TypeElement `xml:"Type"`
}
type TypeElement struct {
    Type string `xml:"Type"`
}
```

Any help as to how i could do it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What is your question? Btw you have a typo, element inside `<Request>` is `<Types>` (note the **s**), and you used `Type` in the Go tag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

follow is a example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Type struct {
    AType string `xml:"Type"`
}

type Types struct {
    Type []Type
}

type Request struct {
    Types Types
}

func main() {
    var data = `
<Request>
    <Types>
        <Type>
            <Type>Type1</Type>
        </Type>
        <Type>
            <Type>Type2</Type>
        </Type>
    </Types>
</Request>`
    var r Request
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", r)
}
```